# Есть ли такая функция в Java?

Tags: java, bat

Помню когда прогал по фану батники в batch коде можно было взять переменную или строку в 2 символа "%" и вставить в любую часть кода, она была чем то типа alias

```
@echo off
j=4
echo ttt%j%ttt
```

Вывод получался ttt4ttt

Comment: Не совсем то, но вот: [String.format](https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questmultithreading.level02.lecture06)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так в точности как у вас точно нельзя. Java объектно-ориентированный язык и вся функциональность инкапсулирована в пределах специально предназначенных для этого классах. Поэтому для осуществления такой вставки всё будет зависеть от контекста решаемых проблем. Если вы хотели бы вставить ваш символ в произвольное место в строку используйте класс `StringBuilder` который имеет возможность изменять свое состояние поэтому сделайте следующие.
Создайте объект класса `StringBuilder` и в конструктор передайте строку.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("tttttt");
```

После чего внутреннее состояние объекта инициализируется переданной вашей строкой и теперь у вас возникает возможность взаимодействовать с объектом путем вызовов соответствующих для этого методов. Для вставки символа в середину созданой вами строки вызовите метод для объекта `builder`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("tttttt");
builder.insert(3, 't');
```

После чего можно распечатать результат на консоль.

```
System.out.println(builder);
```

В итоге вы получаете такую строку `ttt4ttt`.
Если подробно то метод `insert` первым аргументом принимает индекс или же позицию куда вы хотите  вставить символ (индексация символов начинается с 0) вторым аргументом метод принимает символ который вы хотите вставить в строку.
Функциональность данного класса этим не ограничивается за более обширной информацией обратитесь к официальной [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,char))